# A German company is accusing me of stealing and threatening to confiscate compensation for my service. Is it in the legal right to do so?

Tags: european-union, germany, theft

**Backstory:**

I (a natural person) cooperated with a German company (I assume a legal person). The cooperation consisted of a digital marketing service for the company. I did not ask for money for this service, but rather non-monetary compensation (goods). All of the communication between us has a written record, as it was done over email. Since this is happening in a specific industry, there are terms that are generally known in that industry. I used these terms without further explanation or clarification, thinking that the company is familiar with their meaning. After examining all of our written exchanges, I concluded that the company omitted almost every possible detail that would otherwise have been clearly defined, stated, or further specified.

In our early exchanges, I wrote that I would not charge any fees prior to the completion of my service, i.e. no up-front fee. I don't know how this stands legally, but I never stated or suggested that there would be no costs or charges after I completed my service. At no point in our exchanges did I suggest that I would provide my service free of charge. After recent conversations and exchanges, I believe that the company is not familiar with the industry terms. There's also a possibility that there's a language barrier. The terms that I used to describe the goods suggest and are generally accepted to mean that the goods are to be kept.

Without any questioning or request for further clarification, the company sent the goods via regular mail. No signed contract, mutual agreement, or explicit suggestion that the goods were to be returned. I examined all our emails, including the ones leading up to the package being sent, and the company never mentioned that the package was to be returned or kept temporarily.

Here's where things get more complicated. I partially fulfilled my service, and there is circumstantial evidence that suggests that my efforts have already significantly contributed to the company with increased sales, brand recognition, and an expanded customer base. As someone who very closely follows this small industry, I can draw a strong correlation between my partially fulfilled service and the company's rise and industry recognition. Needless to say, all of this is disputable.

The reason why I haven't fully fulfilled my service yet is due to the company causing severe delays that haven't allowed me to do so. I have already invested hundreds of hours into my service, used my knowledge and expertise, as well as resources.

**Current development**

The company requested from me to send the goods back and claimed the goods to be company property. As of now, the company threatened to report the goods as stolen. Is this any different than accusing me of stealing the goods? From my understanding, from the moment a formal police report has been made, the company will be held accountable for making a false accusation (if I prove my innocence). Does it have the right to confiscate the goods?

Based on the description I gave, can you conclude whether the company has broken any laws?

If you need any additional specifications, or have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148867/discussion-on-question-by-guywithlotsquestions-a-german-company-is-accusing-me-o); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: "I used these terms without further explanation or clarification, thinking that the company is familiar with their meaning." is the meaning in a normal dictionary the way you used it, or is the law familiar with their meaning as you used it?

Comment: Thank you for the question. The term isn't in the dictionary, as far as I am aware. Likewise, I am not familiar with the term in the law, it's likely in there but not labeled with the same name.

However, with the provided context (through email exchanges), one from the industry could understand and conclude its meaning.

Comment: not in the dictionary means, it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

We don't answer question for specific cases here. You should get a lawyer.

However, some generic information:

For employees, German companies are required to give them the tools to do their job. It is not uncommon to pay for an employees specialized stand-up desk or brand new Mac-Book if they work from home. Even if it gets send to them and used by them, it is not a gift. It remains company property. If the employment ends, the goods have to be given back.

No such requirement exists for contractors. They are expected to have their own tools, since they are paid for the results of their, not their work per se.

So just sending you something you need for the job does not mean it now belongs to you. Unless otherwise specified, it still remains the property of the company.

However, it is the company's task to ship their own property if they want it elsewhere. To you. And From you.

So in the above case, the company will probably pay to have the MacBook shipped back to them. Because that is a really good investment. They may make a really good offer to the ex-employee to keep the desk for a nominal fee, because shipping it back to the company where nobody needs it is just pointless expenses. But it is their right to do it. If they want to spent that money on shipping the desk, they can. But they need to pay for it. All you have to do is open the door to the shipping company when they come to pick it up.

Since you have no real contract, "my email could be interpreted that way if read in the correct context" is a thing that is not really clear cut. A good lawyer on their side might eat you for breakfast, a good lawyer on your side may eat them for breakfast.

Whether or not the police in your home country will do something, or whether it will just be stuck in buerocratic red tape internationally forever is something we cannot possibly say. On the other hand it is something you don't want to find out at 04:30 in the morning with an armed man breaking down your door on a day you didn't think about it.

So to answer your question: get a lawyer, because it is not as clear cut as you think it is. Whether you are "innocent" is debatable, so get someone from the debate team to look at it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your opinion! I'm aware this is very specific, but I thought I'd share the details to get better opinions and judgements.

It is most certainly not clear cut, I'm well aware of that. The thing is, I am not employed by this company, nor was I ever employed by it. So, I cannot relate to the MacBook or desk scenario. This is not what I meant when I wrote that I needed the goods to carry out the job. 

Also, armed men breaking down my door at 04:30 in the morning sounds like a scene from a movie, and I get your humor, but it's a bit extreme.

Comment: I also want to add, the company was well aware of what my service offered and concluded, at least in the sense that a large audience reach was in question, a highly professional quality of the service, and someone who has a "place" in the industry (me). At least from the way I look at it, if I were a company, I wouldn't be able to reasonably assume that someone would do this for free. Even if the company understood that the goods were not to be sent back, it would be walking away with much more gain than I would be with the value of their goods. 

As you pointed out already, it's debatable.